# get jvectormap inside a content page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jvectormap, contentplaceholder

Im having hard time getting the jvectormap inside my content page, i test on a blank web form i worked but now on content page i cant get it work,

```
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
        <script src="js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("H");
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Body" runat="server">
  <div id="world-map"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the JvectorMap

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#world-map').vectorMap();
});
```

http://jvectormap.com/tutorials/getting-started/